# How do I take text from cell A1 and put it in the middle of a sentence in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take text from cell A1 and use it within the text of another cell on the same sheet, let's call it cell A20, by using VBA. If cell A1 said "dog", I want the code to insert that word in the middle of the pre-existing text in cell A20, "My favorite thing about my **__** is its color."

For clarity, I'll say that the rest of the text in cell A20 will never change, so it can be typed into the code itself if that's easiest (I'd probably prefer that anyway). Hopefully this makes some sense, but please comment and let me know if it doesn't. Thanks in advance to whoever helps me out!

Comment: do you need vba for that? what for?

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK that A20 is not altered, the desired change can be put into another cell using this worksheet formula:

```
  =SUBSTITUTE(A20,"__",A1)
```

VBA to accomplish the same thing - but now replacing the original string in A20:

```
  Sub InsertText()
      Range("A20").Value = Replace(Range("A20").Value, "__", Range("A1").Value)
  End Sub
```